# OAuth 2 Authorization-Code-Flow Jwt and Client-Crendentials-Flow Jwt

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

Authorization-Code-Flow Jwt is generally used to authenticate a human user.

Client-Crendentials-Flow Jwt is generally used to authenticate a server client.

We are using the same oauth 2 server for these two kinds of flows.

However, some services do not like a human user uses their jwt to call them.

So what is the best practise to prevent Authorization-Code-Flow Jwt be used to authenticate a call to backend-to-backend only service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

If your backend services are deployed in the same cluster or network and the service is backend-to-backend only, you should not expose / publish its APIs to the world. This approach doesn't require modifying code but can be done at the infrastructure (network, firewall) layer.

If your backend services are deployed in different clusters / networks, then you should handle at the application layer (your backend code) to not support `Authorization-code-flow`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve what you need. Tuan LE CONG mentioned that you could restrict access at the infrastructure level — you can make sure that services that have user tokens are not able to call those services that expect client credentials tokens.

Another way is to make authorization decisions based on the access tokens. JWT access tokens consist of claims, and in every token, you should find a `sub` claim. This identifies the subject of the token. For user tokens (those created with authorization code flow) you will have the user's ID, email, or similar information in the `sub` claim. For service-to-service tokens (created with client credentials flows), you will have the service's ID (e.g., the OAuth client ID) in the `sub` claim. You can reject any requests that do not contain a valid client ID. This validation can be performed either by the service itself or by an API gateway.

Comment: Hi @Michal Trojanowski, could you please add the source of your answer please? Is there any standard specification that mentions the "sub" claim should have the value of the client ID for authorization code access tokens? Also according to the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519.html#section-4.1.2 spec, the "sub" claim is an optional claim. So I assume we cannot always rely on the "sub" claim to check whether the token is client credentials or not.

Comment: There is no standard that mandates what should be used as the value of the `sub` claim. I have softened the language of my answer to reflect that. As to whether you can rely on the `sub` claim — when you have an API that consumes tokens it means that you're also in control of the authorization server that issues tokens. So you can make sure that the token contains claims that you need to perform authorization decisions.

Comment: hi @Michal Trojanowski, Found the following two specifications which say about the subject identifier of the client credentials and authorization code grant access tokens https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7523#section-3. It says the client credential tokens must send the client ID as the value of the "sub" claim. I guess we can distinguish two token types using the "sub" claim according to this. The only issue is can we say a JWT token is an authorization code grant access token by just validating the "sub" claim value is not the client ID? Because we already know what the client ID is.

Comment: Note that the document you linked is a Profile. This means it is a standard that facilitates interoperability but does not have to be implemented by authorization servers. If your server adheres to that profile then you can safely make all the assumptions included in it.

Comment: As for your second question — normally you shouldn't be concerned about whether a token was issued with the code flow. The important part is the content of the token and what you expect in the API. You can check the `sub` claim, whether it contains one of the client IDs you expect. If it doesn't, then you reject that token/handle differently, etc. You don't care what flow was used.